# Getting syntax error; value expected

Tags: c#, syntax

Hi i am getting a normal syntax error but what am i missing here.

Getting error on this line:

```
 Gateway.CreateTimereportsAsync(TimereportComposite[]);
```

Its in the end at **[ ]**.

**UPDATE**

This is TimereportComposite:

```
 ServiceReference.TimereportComposite TimereportComposite = new ServiceReference.TimereportComposite();
```

Comment: What is a `TimereportComposite`? My guess is that it's an array of some sort and you need to give in an index, like `TimereportComposite[1]` or whatever's appropriate. Otherwise, see Reed's answer.

Comment: what is this TimereportComposite ?is it array ?or variable?or method?

Comment: Hey tell me man , What is that ??? Can i see your full code here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `TimereportComposite` is a variable which is already an array, and the method expects an array, you would pass it directly:

```
Gateway.CreateTimereportsAsync(TimereportComposite);
```

Given the name of the method (GenerateTimereport**s**Async), I suspect this is the case.

If the method expects a single value, and the variable is an array, you'd need to provide an index:

```
Gateway.CreateTimereportsAsync(TimereportComposite[0]);
```

Comment: TimereportComposite is a ServiceReference added it to my question as update. And the CreateTimereportsAsync is a soapclient

Comment: When i do like this: Gateway.CreateTimereportsAsync(TimereportComposite[0]); i get error: **Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type**

Comment: @AlexanderMogren You're not showing the syntax required for CreateTimereportsAsync, but I suspect the first option is more likely what you want.  The types may not match, though.

Comment: @AlexanderMogren I'm happy to keep trying to help - there just isn't enough information here to give you the right answer :(

Comment: I am so bad at this at what is what. CreateTimereportsAsync comes from a added servicereference

Comment: @AlexanderMogren You can still view it in the Object Browser to see what it expects.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30586/discussion-between-alexander-mogren-and-reed-copsey)

Comment: Interesting that when i look in the object browser CreateTimereportsAsync in not there.

Answer (score 0):

What is this `TimereportComposite`? Is it an array? Or a variable? Or a method?

If it is an array:

Must add the correct index of array(Size) when passing parameter

```
Gateway.CreateTimereportsAsync(TimereportComposite[0]);
```

If it is a variable:

```
Gateway.CreateTimereportsAsync(TimereportComposite);
```

If it is a method:

```
Gateway.CreateTimereportsAsync(TimereportComposite());
```

Answer (score -1):

If `TimereportComposite` is a class name, then put `new` before it along with an array length.

```
Gateway.CreateTimereportsAsync(new TimereportComposite[0]);
```

Otherwise, if `TimereportComposite` is a variable, then remove the `[]`.

Comment: `new TimereportComposite[0]` that doesn't make any sense. You're passing in a new array of length zero? Just... no. I seriously doubt that would even compile.

Comment: As I mention in my answer, if `TimereportComposite` is a class (it could be since the answer was not clear about that), then `new TimereportComposite[0]` is valid:  it creates an array of 0 length of the class.

Comment: "I seriously doubt that would even compile" Try it and know for sure before you discount it.  It's perfectly valid and will compile.

Comment: Gateway.CreateTimereportsAsync(new TimereportComposite[0]); it's total wrong . it's pass a new array !!! If it is an class , then how to you use [] ?? class only allowed for () .

Comment: () is used when doing `new` when instantiating a single object.  When doing `new` to create an array, you use [].  And yes, it will create a new array.  The OP hasn't given any context to indicate an empty array could be wrong.

Comment: @MattHouser Fair enough about not checking on my part, but of all solutions, I find a new empty array to be, by far, the least likely. It just doesn't make any sense.